# Poisson-distribution, expactancy value E[X²]

Tags: poisson-distribution

I want to solve this:

$E[X^2]=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} k^2 e^{-\lambda}\frac{\lambda^k}{k!}$

My try:

$E[X^2]=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} k^2 e^{-\lambda}\frac{\lambda^k}{k!}=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} k^2 e^{-\lambda}\frac{\lambda^k}{k!}$

Indexshift and reduction:

$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (k+1) e^{-\lambda}\frac{\lambda^{k+1}}{k!}$

Now I am not sure if this is legal:

$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \lambda ke^{-\lambda}\frac{\lambda^k}{k!}+\lambda e^{-\lambda}\frac{\lambda^k}{k!}$

$\lambda\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=0}^n ke^{-\lambda}\frac{\lambda^k}{k!}+\sum_{k=0}^n e^{-\lambda}\frac{\lambda^k}{k!}$

I know that $\sum_{k=0}^n ke^{-\lambda}\frac{\lambda^k}{k!}=\lambda$ and

$\sum_{k=0}^n e^{-\lambda}\frac{\lambda^k}{k!}=1$

Thus:

$\lambda \lim_{n\to\infty} \lambda+1=\lambda(\lambda+1)$

I know that the result should be right, but I am not sure if it is legal to split the sum, like I did after inculding the limit.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, as long as every $a_n$ and $b_n$ is nonnegative, one has $$\sum_na_n+b_n=\sum_na_n+\sum_nb_n.$$ Only, the identity holds in $[0,\infty]$, for example this could mean that $\infty=42+\infty$.